# How to set the referenced collection of many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have to entities which have many-to-many relationship.

```
public class M1 { M1Id int; ICollection<M2> M2s { get; set; } }
public class M2 { M2Id int; ICollection<M1> M1s { get; set; } }
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public DbSet<M1> M1s{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<M2> M2s{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<M1>().HasMany<M2>(e => e.M2s).WithMany(c => c.M1s)
            .Map(c =>
            {
                c.MapLeftKey("M1"); 
                c.MapRightKey("M2Id"); 
                c.ToTable("M1AndM2");
            });
```

And I need to create an `M1` from VM in the post method.

```
var M1 = new M1
{
    Id = M1Vm.M1Id,
    // ....
    M2s = db.M1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.M1Id == M1Vm.M1Id).M2s
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(M1).State = EntityState.Modified; // Error
        UpdateM2s(M1, M1Vm.NewM2s); // Update table M1AndM2
```

It will raise the following error when set the `State` of the `M1`.

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

The `UpdateM2s` will run `M1.M2s.Add(m2)` or `M1.M2s.Remove(m2)` after the comparison. The following is the code.

```
    private void UpdateM2s(M1 m1, IEnumerable<NewM2s> newM2s)
    {
        foreach (var newM2 in newM2s)
        {
            // Add many-to-many relationship
            if (newM2.Assigned && !m1.M2s.Any(c => c.M2Id == newM2.M2Id))
            {
                var m2 = new M2 { M2Id = newM2.M2Id, .... };
                db.M2.Attach(m2);
                m1.M2s.Add(m2);
            }
            // Remove many-to-many relationship
            else if (!newM2.Assigned && m1.M2s.Any(c => c.Id == assigned.Id))
            {
                var m2 = new M2 { M2Id = newM2.M2Id, .... };
                db.M2.Attach(m2); // Same Error
                m1.M2s.Remove(m2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line...

```
M2s = db.M1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.M1Id == M1Vm.M1Id).M2s
```

...loads the `M1` entity with key `M1Vm.M1Id` from the database and attaches it to the context. Then it loads its `M2s` collection via lazy loading. At the same time you are creating a new entity `M1` with the same key `Id = M1Vm.M1Id` and attaching it to the context by setting its state with `db.Entry(M1).State = EntityState.Modified`. So, you have two objects with the same key attached to the context which is what the exception is complaining about.

You could try to fix the problem by loading the `M2s` only, without the parent:

```
M2s = db.M1.Select(m1 => m1.M2s).FirstOrDefault(x => x.M1Id == M1Vm.M1Id)
```

However, I believe the better approach would be to not create a new object at all, but load the original `M1` from the database including the `M2s` collection and then update the object graph with the view model:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var m1 = db.M1.Include(m => m.M2s).FirstOrDefault(x => x.M1Id == M1Vm.M1Id);
    db.Entry(m1).CurrentValues.SetValues(M1Vm);
    UpdateM2(m1, M1Vm.NewM2s);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit**

Now that I see the `UpdateM2` method I suggest that you change that as well. In the `else` part you are creating a new `M2` with the same key as another m2 that already has been included and attached in the query for `m1`. Hence you get the same exception about two attached objects with the same key again, this time just refering to `M2` and not `M1`. You can try to change the `else` block like so:

```
else if (!newM2.Assigned)
{
    var m2 = m1.M2s.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == newM2.Id);
    if (m2 != null)
    {
        m1.M2s.Remove(m2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the last solution. However, the same error occurs at the line `db.M2.Attach(m2);` in `UpdateM2s()` when removing a many-to-many relationship (see the bottom of the updated question).

Comment: BTW, the `// Add many-to-many relationship` part of the method `UpdateM2s` works.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: I've tried to fix the new exception. See my Edit above.